# Question about proof that $\delta(f(x)) = \sum_i\frac{\delta(x_i - x)}{|df/dx_i|}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

From an exercise and proof in *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*:

> [image]

**Question:** The author instructs us to "expand $f(x)$ near such points in a Taylor series, **keeping the first nonzero term**.  This is what the proof answer provides when it assumes that $f(x) = f'(x_i)(x-x_i)$.  But why do we only keep the first non-zero term?  What about the other terms?  Do we have that $f^n(x_i) = 0$ for $n > 1$ If so, why?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to expand in a series; indeed there is no need for $f$ to have more than one derivative at all in order to make sense of $\delta(f(x))$.

What is really happening is that you locally invert $f$. That is, $f$, being a differentiable function that is assumed to never have zero derivative at any of its zeros, can be locally inverted around each of its zeros. So you split the domain into $n+1$ pieces; on $n$ of them, $f$ has exactly one zero and is locally invertible, and on the last one $f$ has no zero. The last one should "obviously" not contribute to the integration.

For the other pieces, say $h_k$ is the local inverse of $f$ on $I_k$. Then you have $\int_{I_k} g(x) \delta(f(x)) dx = \int_{f(I_k)} g(h_k(u)) \delta(u) \left | \frac{dx}{du} \right | du$. (The inclusion of the absolute value can be justified by doing case work based on the sign of $\frac{dx}{du}$ on $I_k$, paying attention to the orientation of the domain in the two cases.)

From the inverse function theorem you have $\left | \frac{dx}{du}(u) \right | = \frac{1}{|f'(h_k(u))|}$ (the usual thing you do during $u$ substitution), so by the definition of the delta function you get $\frac{g(h_k(0))}{|f'(h_k(0))|}$ from the integration on $I_k$.

Comment: What do you mean by "inverting $f$"? Do you mean considering $f^{-1}$?

Comment: @user1770201 $f$ doesn't actually have an inverse usually, but it has local inverses in the regions where it is increasing or decreasing. By splitting the integration domain, you can perform the inversion on each subinterval, which allows you to do the integration by a $u$ substitution.

Answer (score 1):

This formula only works for simple zeroes for which df/dx does not cancel.  A good proof can be found in Kanwal's book "Generalized Functions" pp. 49-50

Comment: I have located this alternative proof [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/george.w.singer/trash/png/alternative_proof.png).  Two questions: (i) how does $f'(x)$ end up in the denominator under the integral? (ii) what is meant by "simple zeros" vs. "higher-order zeros"?

Comment: @user1770201 A zero of a differentiable function is simple if the derivative doesn't vanish at the zero. $f'$ shows up in the denominator because of the usual machinery of $u$ substitution.