# Understanding an instance of Integration by Substitution w/the Dirac Delta Function

Tags: integration, substitution, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

From Kanwal's *Generalized Functions* pg. 49:

> [image]

**Question:** How does the author move from

$$
∫_{-∞}^∞ δ[f(x)]ϕ(x)dx = ∫_{-∞}^∞ δ(y)\frac{ϕ[x(y)]}{f'(x)}dy
$$

via Integration by Substitution at the start of the second equation? Specifically how does $f'(x)$ end up in the denominator (this makes no sense to me since $x$ is now interpreted as some fixed constant?)?  It seems to me that we should actually have

$$
∫_{-∞}^∞ δ[f(x)]ϕ(x)dx = ∫_{-∞}^∞ δ(y)ϕ[x(y)]f'(y)dy
$$

How am I mistaken?

Comment: The most recent time that I answered this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4039864/question-about-proof-that-deltafx-sum-i-frac-deltax-i-xdf-dx-i/4039868#4039868 (Though I see this was also asked by you...)

Comment: In any case it is indeed misleading to write $f'(x_1)$ there as they did. It is $f'(y)$, but it is indeed in the denominator as it usually is when you do integration by substitution.

Comment: The Dirac Delta is NOT a function, and the linear functional is NOT an integral.  See [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function) for the definition of the Dirac Delta Composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is only about the change of variable you can read it backwards. We want to give meaning to $\delta(f(x))$, start with
$$ 
\int_{\mathbb{I}} \delta(f(x)) \, \phi(f(x))  \, f'(x) dx \; ,
$$
where $\mathbb{I}$ is some neighbourhood of the point $x_1$ where $f(x_1)=0$. And now change variables. Let $y=f(x)$, $dy = f'(x) dx$ , then
$$ 
\int_{\mathbb{I}} \delta(f(x)) \, \phi(f(x))  \, f'(x) dx \; =
\;  \int_{f(\mathbb{I})} \delta(y) \, \phi(y)  \, dx \; = \; \phi(0) .
$$
This is independent of the neighbourhood $\mathbb{I}$. In this region $f'(x)$ is nonzero by assumption. The distribution $\delta(f(x))$ must constraint $x=x_1$ and cancel the factor $ f'(x)$, thus the only possibility is
$$  \delta(f(x)) \; = \; \frac{ \delta(x-x_1) }{ f'(x_1) } \; . $$

Thus
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{I}} \delta(f(x)) \, \phi(f(x))  \, f'(x) dx \; & =
\; \int_{\mathbb{I}} \delta(x-x_1) \, \phi(f(x))  \, \frac{f'(x)}{f'(x_1)}  \\
&= \; \phi(f(x_1))  \, \frac{f'(x_1)}{f'(x_1)}  \; = \; \phi(0)
\end{align}

---

#### A simple example

Calculate the integral  (for $x_0>0$)
$$ 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \delta(x^2 - x_0^2) \, \phi(x)   dx \; .
$$
From one side we could use $y=x^2-x_0^2$, $dy = 2x dx$. Let $x(y) = \sqrt{y+x_0^2}$ where $x(0) = x_0$, then
$$ 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \delta(x^2 - x_0^2) \, \phi(x)   dx \; = \; 
\int_{-x_0^2}^{\infty} \delta(y) \frac{\phi[x(y)]}{2x(y)} dy \; = \; \frac{\phi(x_0)}{2x_0} \; .
$$
On the other hand, we could use the expression for the delta function. Let $f(x)=x^2-x_0^2$. In this region, $f$ has only one zero (that happens at $x=x_0$) and $f'(x)=2x > 0$. Thus
$$ \delta(x^2-x_0^2) = \frac{\delta(x-x_0)}{2x_0} \; , \text{ for } x> 0 \; . $$
Evidently, this gives the same answer for the integral.

**Note** that the statement of the book can be generalised to incorporate negative values to the derivative and more than one point where $f(x)=0$. In this example, for the general case where $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x^2-a^2$ the Dirac delta is
$$ (\delta \circ f)(x) \; = \; 
\delta(x^2-a^2) \; = \; \frac{1}{2\vert a \vert } \, \Big( \,\delta(x-a) + \delta(x+a)   \,  \Big) \; .$$

Comment: Do we interpret $f'(x)$ in the top equation as $f'(x(y))$?

Comment: $f'(x)$ in the top equation is a book error.  It seems if we interpret it instead as either $f'(y)$ or $f'(x(y))$, then the Integration by Substitution fails, no?

Comment: Indeed the notation of the book is not very good, but the $\delta(y)$ constraint $f(x)$ to be zero. Then the $f'(x)$ is evaluated at the $x$ such that $f(x)=0$. I will rewrite my solution for it be more clear.